# How to filter strings in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have strings:

```
"C0.test.trd.co"
"C1.trd.co"
"C2.test.trd.co"
```

etc.
I want to replace the strings after "C0" "C1" "C2" etc. in powerhsell.

If ends with "trd.co" or "test.trd.co" then it should be "prod.trd.co"
In an example after conversion:

```
"C0.prod.trd.co"
"C1.prod.trd.co"
"C2.prod.trd.co"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the pattern `(?<=C[0-9]\.)(?:test\.trd\.co|trd\.co)` and if the string matches that pattern, replace with `prod.trd.co`. If the digits coming after `C` could be more than 1, then you can add a `+` after `[0-9]`: `(?<=C[0-9]+\.)...`.

```bash
'C0.test.trd.co',
'C1.trd.co',
'C2.test.trd.co' -replace '(?<=C[0-9]\.)(?:test\.trd\.co|trd\.co)', 'prod.trd.co'
```

See https://regex101.com/r/Uplfbm/1 for regex details.

Comment: You beat me to it with a quicker, shorter script. Nice one :D I did not know this way.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.4

This script prints the new strings based on the replaced patterns. You can extend this by writing to a file, saving in a variable, etc.

```
# Define here your input strings
$strings = @(
    "C0.test.trd.co",
    "C1.trd.co",
    "C2.test.trd.co",
    "C3.trd.co"
)

# Define the regex expression. If it starts with "anything.TEST" and/or ends with ".trd.co"
$pattern = "^C\d+(\.test)?\.trd\.co$"

# Loop through each input string
foreach ($string in $strings) {
    # Check if the string matches the pattern
    if ($string -match $pattern) {
        # Replace the input strings if matches with the pattern (So this will replace the "anything.test.trd.co" and the "anything.trd.co")
        $newString = $string -replace "\.test\.trd\.co|\.trd\.co", ".prod.trd.co"
        Write-Output $newString
    } else {
        Write-Output "String doesn't match the pattern: $string"
    }
}
```